# Codeigniter- form with optional file uploading field working unexpectedly

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a form which asks for user's name and description and an optional field of image uploading. When the user uploads the image I want the name of the image to be changed and stored into the database and if no image is uploaded then a default name is stored in the database. It works fine if user uploads an image but if he does not then nothing is being uploaded into the database. 
This is the controller function :

```
function store()
{
    $this->load->model('campus_m');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['file_name'] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i','-',iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$this->input->post('name')));
    $config['file_name'] = trim($config['file_name'],'-').now().'.jpg';                         

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('goods', 'Goods', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[12]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('campus_write_v');
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($_FILES['userfile']);
        if (empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
            if(!$query = $this->campus_m->create_review("Marla-overdoses1360186300.jpg")){
                $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has not been stored.';
                $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
            }
            else {
                $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has been stored. ';
                $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            if($this->upload->do_upload()){
                if(!$query = $this->campus_m->create_review($config['file_name'])){
                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has not been stored.';
                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                }
                else {
                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has been stored. ';
                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                foreach ($error as $rows => $r)
                {
                    echo $r ;                 
                }
                $this->load->view('campus_write_v');                             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the view :

```
<?php
                $attributes = array('id' => 'contactform');
                echo form_open_multipart('campus/store', $attributes);
                ?>
                <div>
                <?php
                echo form_label('Title of Area');
                $data = array(
                    'name'        => 'name',
                    'id'          => 'name',
                    'placeholder' => 'Location and name of the place',
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'value'       => set_value("name") 
                    );

                echo form_input($data);    
                ?>
                </div>

                <div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                    'name'        => 'goods',
                    'id'          => 'goods',
                    'placeholder' => 'Tell us about the place',
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'value'       => set_value("goods"),
                    'rows'   => '20',
                    'cols'        => '50'
                    );

                echo form_textarea($data);    
                ?>
                </div>
                <div>
            <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" size="20" />
        </div>

                <div>
                    <?php
                    $data = array(
                    'class'        => 'button',
                    'value'       => 'Submit',
                    'id'          =>"submit"
                    );

                echo form_submit($data);
                    ?>

        </div>
                  <?php     echo form_close();
                    ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Should I assume that you are not getting the message `The answer has not been stored.`

Answer (score 2):

I will solve this in this way:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $photo['image'] = $data['file_name']; // Name of image
} else {
    $photo['image'] = "Name"; // Name that you want
}
```

This is the short code of uploads controller.

Comment: this line work for me... `$this->upload->initialize($config)`